# how to Apply corresponding background color to rows in lwc based on an array stored in javascript file

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have an array stored in javascript which has data and corresponding colors to be applied to the rows in html file.

```
result 
{listFloors: Array(3)
listFloors: Array(3)
0:
floorNumber: 3
size: 300
spaces: Array(1)
0: {color: "#FCDFFF", residentialSpace: {…}, size: 300, width: "20px"}
```

I want to use the color variable to set the background color of each row along with data.I have tried using the below:
style="background-color:{!spaces.color};">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of having just one row, you'd need to use a getter:

```
get backgroundColor() {
    return `background-color:"${result.spaces[0].color}"`;
}
```

And then reference it on the markup:

```
style={!backgroundColor}
```

You're saying you have several rows, so maybe you could compute all the background-color properties to apply, and store them in the array you iterate:

```
// When you receive your results array
result.spaces.map(space => { space.computedBackgroundColor = `background-color:${space.color}`});
```

And then in your template:

```
<template for:each={result.spaces} for:item="space">
    <div class="row" style={space.computedBackgroundColor}>
</template>
```

Comment: when I am using style={!space.computedBackgroundColor}, it says Template expression doesn't allow UnaryExpressionlwc. Also I have all the computed data in my array along with the color to be applied.

Comment: I mixed up aura and lwc syntax, try now

Comment: Hi, I have applied the below code:                                                                                          for(let i=0;i<result.listFloors.length;i++)
    {
     this.computedBackgroundColor=result.listFloors[i].spaces.map(space =>{ space.color = `background-color:${space.color}`});
     console.log('computedBackgroundColor',JSON.stringify(this.computedBackgroundColor));
    }     but getting error:TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'color' of object '#<Object>'
    at eval (stackingPlan.js:4)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at eval (stackingPlan.js:4)

Comment: Also  <template for:each={floors.spaces} for:item="spaces" > 
                <td  key={spaces.Id} style={spaces.computedBackgroundColor}>                     this is not working error:at rule or css expected

Comment: Maybe you need `background-color:"${result.spaces[0].color}"`;, with the "?